# All instances of Wordpress stops responding on same server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, debugging

I have a server with several websites with `Wordpress`, mapped to a virtual-host folder with `Lighttpd`.  I also have other websites, non-wp, mapped in same way.

I'm experiencing random crashes of `wordpress` - ie. suddenly all three wordpress websites stops responding, and I have to restart the server to fix the problem. The other websites are unaffected.

I'm at a loss for how to debug this problem. I've looked through some error logs, nothing stands out.  Could this be a `php` and/or `mysql` problem?  The server is a very strong box, 8-core, 32GB RAM.

Error logs dumps:

**LIGHTTPD**: `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`: 
There is nothing above `PHP Notice` level.

**MYSQL**: `/var/log/mysql/error.log` (quite a few of these, but also whilst site is working).:

```
140320 17:45:46 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './2famousTV/wp_comments' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
```

**SERVER**: `/var/log/auth.log` (there's a bunch of these, but not enough to DDOS):

```
Mar 20 20:13:42 Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal sshd[3535]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for no-reverse-dns.metronet-uk.com [109.111.197.158] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

I hadn't activated php error log, but will post results if new crash.  Would really appreciate some feedback on debug strategies or inspired hunches towards the culprit(s). Thanks.

Comment: the possibilities are near infinite

Comment: You'll need to narrow it down.

Comment: Yes, no doubt. But how?